# Colorbox Scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox, css-transitions

I have an image that opens in a a lightbox (Colorbox is the script). When the image opens I added a CSS3 Animation. Works great but at first the lightbox has scrollbars which disappear once the animation is complete.

How do I prevent the lightbox from showing scrollbars at all?

Code:

```
#start{
  /* Width and Height of the Image */
  width:526px;
  height:450px;
}

<div class="hide">
<div id="start">
 <img src="/Images/designs/start-large.jpg" class="animated rollIn"> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add `overflow:hidden;` to your CSS style of the div / img. Or try `overflow:visible;` if it cuts off something.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` works great!  Note: `overflow:visible` does not fix the scrollbar issue.

Answer (score 5):

Set the colorbox setting `scrolling` to `false` to disable scrollbars on content.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `colorbox.resize()` to automatic calculate its size or use `overflow hidden` to the parents of your content.
Both ways works.

Answer (score 4):

```
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:hidden !important;}
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Add **scrolling: false**

```
$.colorbox({
  inline:true, 
  width:'95%',
  scrolling: false // *********
});
```